# How can I match annual panel data given in fiscal years and calendar years?

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data

I want to perform a regression analysis with annual panel data. However, most of the corporate data is  given in fiscal years whereas other variables (such as annual ranking data) are given in calendar years. How can I match the data? Since I only have annual data I'm not able to match the quarters of the fiscal year to the calendar year.

Thanks for your help!